# Need Help in Recurssive Query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in sql recursive query, for example purpose i m providing sample table with insert script.

```
CREATE   TABLE Details(
parentid varchar(10), DetailComponent varchar(10) , DetailLevel int)
GO

INSERT INTO Details 
SELECT '','7419-01',0 union all
SELECT '7419-01','44342-00',1 union all
SELECT '7419-01','45342-00',1 union all
SELECT '7419-01','46342-00',1 union all
SELECT '7419-01','47342-00',1 union all
SELECT '7419-01','48342-00',1 union all
SELECT '7419-01','49342-00',1 union all
SELECT '7419-01','50342-00',1 union all
SELECT '50342-00','51342-00',2 union all
SELECT '7419-01','52342-00',1 union all
SELECT '52342-00','54342-00',2 union all
SELECT '54342-00','54442-00',3 union all
SELECT '54342-00','54552-00',3 union all
SELECT '54552-00','R34S-54',4 union all
SELECT '54552-00','R123-54',4 union all
SELECT '54552-00','R111-54',4 union all
SELECT 'R111-54','R222-54',5 union all
SELECT 'R222-54','52342-00',6 union all
SELECT '7419-01','TEST34-00',1 union all
SELECT 'TEST34-00','445334-00',2 union all
SELECT '445334-00','52342-00',3  union all
SELECT '7419-01','1111-00',1 union all
SELECT '7419-01','1111-00',1 union all
SELECT '1111-00','52342-00',2 
GO

SELECT * FROM Details
```

From the above table data i want a search query , for example if I search data with "52342-00" I want output to be below format using CTE.

```
NULL,'7419-01',0
'7419-01','52342-00',1
'7419-01','52342-00',1
'52342-00','54342-00',2
'54342-00','54552-00',3
'54552-00','R111-54',4
'R111-54','R222-54',5
'R222-54','52342-00',6
```

kindly provide suggestions .

Comment: explain your output please.

Comment: from the table i will search for "52342-00" record , for that record i will check the parentid , take that parentid and check for DetailComponent column and take parentid for this column check for immeidate parent id like upto level 0 , pls let me know if my explanation is good to understand

Comment: NULL,'7419-01',0 // this records is parent for all records
'7419-01','52342-00',1 // in level 2  parentid is '52342-00'  so display 
'7419-01','52342-00',1 // in level 2  parentid is '52342-00'  so display 
'52342-00','54342-00',2 // in level 3  parentid is '54342-00'  so display 
'54342-00','54552-00',3 // in level 4  parentid is '54552-00'  so display this record also
'54552-00','R111-54',4 // in level 5  parentid is 'R111-54'  so display this 
'R111-54','R222-54',5 // for level 6 parentid is 'R222-54' so display this 
'R222-54','52342-00',6 //search for this reocrds '52342-00'

Comment: Please explain the reason you want a cte.

Comment: There seems to be some issue with your data. recursive logic may go into infinite loop. please cross check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your output, you would have to specify the DetailLevel in your cte, since just searching for '52342-00' will return multiple results.

This will get you your results without specifying the exact DetailLevel:

```
;with cte as (
select d.parentid,d.DetailComponent,d.DetailLevel as DetailLevel
from @Details d
  inner join (select distinct DetailComponent, MAX(DetailLevel) as DetailLevel from @Details
                group by DetailComponent) d2
    on d.DetailComponent = d2.DetailComponent
    and d.DetailLevel = d2.DetailLevel
where d.DetailComponent = '52342-00'
union all
select a.parentid, a.DetailComponent,a.DetailLevel
from @Details a
  inner join cte b
    on a.DetailComponent = b.parentid
    and a.DetailLevel < b.DetailLevel
  )

select * from cte
order by DetailLevel asc
```

Comment: Hi Sam cd, when i run the query which u provided it is giving all records as output where as i need output as mentioned in my post above.NULL,'7419-01',0
'7419-01','52342-00',1
'7419-01','52342-00',1
'52342-00','54342-00',2
'54342-00','54552-00',3
'54552-00','R111-54',4
'R111-54','R222-54',5
'R222-54','52342-00',6

Comment: @Ravi that was a typo. You should be selecting from `cte` not from `Details`. It is fixed now

Comment: hi Sam cd, in the cte u r providing DetailLevel = 6 , without DetailLevel  is it possible to get the same output. thanks

Comment: Hi Sam cd, thanks for reply, i ran query it is giving below output,R222-54 52342-00 6
R111-54 R222-54 5
54552-00 R111-54 4
54342-00 54552-00 3
52342-00 54342-00 2
7419-01 52342-00 1
 7419-01 0, but i expected output as below NULL,'7419-01',0
'7419-01','52342-00',1
'7419-01','52342-00',1
'52342-00','54342-00',2
'54342-00','54552-00',3
'54552-00','R111-54',4
'R111-54','R222-54',5
'R222-54','52342-00',6

Comment: @Ravi that is just a matter of order. You can specify `ORDER BY DetailLevel ASC` after the select

Comment: Hi Sam cd, thanks for replay , I mean i m expecting two records with level 1 ,i.e. '7419-01','52342-00',1  and '7419-01','52342-00',1 . where as in query output i m getting only one.

Comment: @Ravi why are you expecting that? That pairing only exists once in your table

Comment: Hi Sam cd, thanks for the reply, i was mistaken by data,the query u provided is correct, only correction required is without mentioning DetailLevel =6 is it possible to get the same output

Comment: @Ravi you can just use the `MAX` DetailLevel, as specified in the edits here

Comment: hi Sam cd, data is displaying in levels 0,1,1,2,2,3,3 format with realtime data, whereas i want output as 0,1,2,3,1,2,3 to display in treeview format.

Comment: @Ravi you might be able to get that format by messing with the `ORDER BY` clause (i.e. `ORDER BY DetailComponent,DetailLevel` or `ORDER BY parentid,DetailLevel`. Otherwise, it is hard to tell without knowing your full input and output

Comment: Thanks for help @Sam cd.